# Nextjs getInitialProps error preventing build on Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, netlify

Hey folks I inherited a project built with nextjs and running on Netlify. I am trying to load a component when a user is using IE. Locally I am am able to render the component view without any issues. But when a build gets ran **(code pushed to a specific branch)** the build fails on Netlify. Netlify does not seem to like the following.

```
const userAgent = props ? props.req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent
```

Open to any suggestions. I am new to Netlify and simply trying to display a component that lets users know that their browser is not supported. Below is the code I have in _document.js

**_document.js**

```
class MyDocument extends Document {

 static async getInitialProps(props) {
  const page = props.renderPage()
  const userAgent = props ? props.req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent

  return {
    ...page,
    userAgent
  }
 }

renderBrowserSupport() {
  let msie = this.props.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ');
  let ie11 = this.props.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/');

  if(msie > 0 || ie11 > 0) {
    return (
      <BrowserSupport/>
    )
  }

  else return false;
}

render() {
  <html lang="en">

  <body>
  {this.renderBrowserSupport()}
  </body>

  </html>
 }
}

export default MyDocument
```

**Error when running npm run build**

```
Cannot read property 'user-agent' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you try doing this instead: `const userAgent = props.req ? props.req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent`

Comment: Still fails @Edrian.

Comment: Cannot read property 'user-agent' of undefined

Comment: Try `props.req.headers ?` instead of `props.req ?`

Comment: now navigator is not defined

Comment: Oh. If that's the case, use `window.navigator` instead

Comment: I dont think that will work either as the window is not available in the nextjs _document.js file. From what I am reading it sounds like anything window related should be utilized in useEffect hook or componentDidMount. A bit stumped now :(

Comment: If window wont work, then the props.req will. The checking props.req is to check if the function is being called from the Server or Client.

Comment: when I use const userAgent = props.req.headers ? props.req.headers['user-agent'] : window.navigator.userAgent and run an npm run build I get a ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: can you console.log the props.req so we can see what it has?

Comment: running npm run dev and logging out props.req it has everything, but when running npm run build it just errors out with window is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into several issues with adding code to _document.js so I went with a different approach which is as follows:

1. created a route update-browser
2. added a component with messaging and alternative browsers to IE
3. added script to check if browser is IE 11 or IE and redirected to update-browser page if so